# "Process of Shipment" vs "Process of Shipping"

Tags: grammar, expressions

Which one of the two expressions "Process of shipment" and "Process of shipping" seem correct? 
The NyTimes seems to be using both of them:

http://www.nytimes.com/2011/12/02/opinion/100-75-50-years-ago.html

http://cityroom.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/08/06/independent-retailers-object-to-jay-zs-distribution-deal-for-new-album/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Shipment*, in the Oxford English Dictionary’s definition, can mean ‘the act of shipping (goods or commodities) for transportation’ and *shipping* can mean ‘the action of putting persons or things on board ship or transporting them by ship’. So not much difference, but since both imply the *act* or *action* of moving stuff around on the sea, the question should perhaps be whether the word *process* is required as well.

Comment: Do you mean we don't need the word process? In a statement like: Your item is still in the process of shipping, do you think the word 'process' need to be removed?

Comment: @Mohammad: I merely say that it's a question that needs to be asked. The answer will depend on the context. I would  guess that in many cases it wouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Shipping -> business or act of sending something

Shipment -> cargo or freight

> **shipping** is the process, **shipment** is the result.

You are shipping the package to someone, when you finish, the shipment will be ready to transport

Answer (score 1):

In my view, 'process of shipping' is correct. A very quick google search on 'process of' seems to indicate that 'process of' is followed by a verb and this is what I would expect in any case. It seems to me that a process is a process of something happening - and that something happening is a verb. Newspapers often use slightly incorrect English which isn't necessarily terrible because English is what we make of it and I think rules can be bent. Having said that, I do think 'process of shipment' doesn't sound quite right anyway. Stick with the verbs in this case :-)

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible but the may differ in meaning  depending on context.  While shipping denotes "**the activity of carrying**", shipment will both refer to "**act of transporting goods**" or "**quantity of goods sent**".